# I would like to transform json data into a csv table

Tags: json

I have this data in a csv and Excel table :

```
{
    "monday": "930-am-7-pm",
    "tuesday": "930-am-7-pm",
    "wednesday": "930-am-7-pm",
    "thursday": "930-am-7-pm",
    "friday": "930-am-7-pm",
    "saturday": "closed",
    "sunday": "closed"
}
```

I'd like to transform them into the table with 7 columns by day and in each day, the opentime into the french format (like 9h30 - 19h).

I'm a beginner so if someone can help me to do that with specific explanation, it would be very nice!

Hope to find someone.

Thank you in advance,

Regards,

I've tried to find a solution in internet but nothing to help me in this specific thing

Comment: What kind of table? Can you show the code you have tried so far? What language is it?

Comment: First it's CSV table (but i have it on an excel table) i have a column with all this kind of datas (from a scraping). I haven't tried any code because i don't know how to use it. What i need it's to transform this line of datas into the same CSV or Excel Table with a column for each day and the opentime date in french format.
Hope it's better to understand. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to convert from JSON to CSV, you can use free online tools like: [https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm](https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm.)

That's the best solution if you don't know how to code and don't have any programming language running on your localhost.

To convert AM/PM dates to the French format, I'm pretty sure you can use Excel functions (such as REGEX_EXTRACT(), for example).

If you really need some other special treatment or an automated solution, you will have to learn some programming language to make a custom script.